# Java iterator used in scala not working properly

Tags: java, scala, iterator, restfb, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to use restfb to pull in a user's likes from facebook. The [docs say](http://restfb.com/#fetching-connections) the iterator supports paging, but this isn't working in my scala code. I expect it's something to do with the `javaConversions` implicits, but I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
import com.restfb.types.{Page, Photo, User}
import com.restfb.{Parameter, Version, DefaultFacebookClient}
import collection.JavaConversions._

class Facebook(accessToken: String) {

  val facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(
    accessToken,
    Version.VERSION_2_4)

  def getInterests = {

    val likes = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/likes", classOf[Page], 
       Parameter.`with`("fields", "id,name,category"))

    likes.getData.map(like => s"id=${like.getId}, name=${like.getName} -- ")
  }
}
```

I've tried changing `likes.getData` to `likes.getData.iterator` but I get an error `org.json4s.package$MappingException: Classes defined in method bodies are not supported.`

What do I need to do to make the iterator returned by `likes.getData` page the results so I can map over all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to map over the connection as well, i.e.:

```
likes.flatMap(likeConn => likeConn.map(like => 
  s"id=${like.getId}, name=${like.getName} -- "))
```

Then it automatically paginates.

Comment: That's because a `Connection` is a page and on that page you find some items (in your case a `Like`). So you need to iterate over the pages and then over the items per page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JavaConverters` instead of `JavaConversions`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val data = likes.getData.asScala.map(like => s"id=${like.getId}, name=${like.getName} -- ")
```

Comment: It's still the same :-(